# Enumerate WCF server endpoints?

Tags: wcf

How do I enumerate the endpoints that my WCF service is listening on? I've found a couple of blog posts that enumerate the configured endpoints (by looking in App.config), but that doesn't help.

I'm hosting a WCF service that configures itself programmatically, and I'd like to get a list of the endpoints that it's listening on, for writing to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

```
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(...);
var endpoints = serviceHost.Description.Endpoints;
```

Comment: ...across all `ServiceHost` instances?

Comment: use reflection to find all     ServiceHost     instances.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you can use reflection to get already-running instances. Unless you know different...?

Comment: Yep. But, when you get down to it, any sufficiently large project might as well not have source code.